# How to fill colors in contour circles in paraview?

Tags: triangulation, paraview

I have a triangulation surface, and there is a point data named `rhoA` on it. I plot `rhoA` in paraview and plot the contour with just one contour value. So you can see many circles on the surface. 
[image: the <code>rhoA</code> on the surface]

But what I need is to fill red colors in the circles and don't show other parts. So how to do it in paraview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **Clip** filter and set the **Clip Type** to *Scalar*. Set the **Scalars** property to `rhoA` and set **Value** to your threshold value. This filter will cut cells, giving you a more precise surface than the **Threshold** filter will.

Here is an example of the results you can expect doing this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can either :

- Use the banded countour filter from VTK, that you will need to expose with a XML only plugin first (hard but precise and efficient)
- Use treshold filter (the cut will not be on the contour, whole cells will be extracted)